# Como crear un exe en CSHARP que al ejecutarlo se genere con un nombre aleatorio

Tags: c#, random, exe, names

Como crear un exe en CSHARP que al ejecutarlo se genere con un nombre aleatorio.
Por ejemplo: ahjh.exe, hjtsa.exe...
Estoy modificando una app y quiero que esta se genere con nombres aleatorios. No pregunten por que quiero hacerla pero va por los lares de que no quiero sea reconocible por otro usuarios.
Hasta ahora no e intentado nada por que no se por donde empezar.
Me valdría támbien un cmd bat o similar. Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y nosotros consideramos eso algo ilegal (estas haciendo un virus? un troyano? un que?)... y en esos casos, directamente no damos ayuda....

Comment: Haz un script en el lenguaje que más te guste, de modo que genere el nombre aleatorio y compile el programa con tal nombre. O que simplemente haga una copia con el nuevo nombre.